# @Named bean not accessible in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, cdi

my environment is: Maven 3, JSF 2, Tomcat 7, Java 6. I am trying to use the java @Named annotations for my beans, that I use in JSF. The project is simple, with one TestBean that has one getter and setter for one property called text.

```
@Named
public class TestBean {
    String text = "Hello World"

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

In my jsf file when I try:

```
#{testBean.text}
```

I get no error but also nothing is shown. What do I have to do to be able to access the bean?

Comment: Tomcat as being a barebones JSP/Servlet container doesn't natively support CDI (like as that it doesn't natively support JSF and all other Java EE artifacts like JPA, EJB, etc). How exactly did you install and enable CDI in Tomcat? You didn't explicitly detail that anywhere in your question, so I guess that you actually didn't do that and that in turn totally explains your concrete problem.

Comment: So I have to explicitely install something like jboss-weld, right?

Comment: Do you have beans.xml in WEB-INF or in META-IN if you code is inside a jar?

Comment: @FilipMajernik yes, you need to include weld and weld servlet in your WAR file.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+install+cdi+in+tomcat

Answer (score 0):

@Named annotation only exposes your bean in EL context, it doesn't give it a scope.

This defaults to 'dependent' pseudo-scope. Dependent beans are not managed, they are just inserted at injection points and that's it.

Try explicitly adding scope. Also you can use built-in @Model stereotype, which is simply a combination of @Named and @RequestScoped.